# Generically retrieve EF object of Type?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

In EF, is there a way to do something similar to the following?

```
'where obj is any EF model object in my context
Public Function GetSomeObject(obj as Object, id as long) as Object 
    Using db as ContextEntities = New ContextEntities
        Dim objType = obj.GetTypeOfObject()
        Dim someObject = db.objType.Find(id)
        'do magic from here on
        ....
    End Using
End Sub
```

This is, of course, a simple example but the idea is to pass in any EF model object to the function and use its type in the `db.modelObjectType.Find(...)` call. So, for example, if I pass in a `customer` object, it retrieves from the `customer` table. If I pass in an `address` object, it retrieves from the address table.

Comment: Is `ContextEntities` a `DbContext`?  If so, there are the generic and non-generic [`DbContext.Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) methods that may be what you are looking for... e.g. `Dim someObject = db.Set(obj.GetType()).Find(id)`.

Comment: Yes, it's a `DBContext`. I have found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675564/in-entity-framework-how-do-i-add-a-generic-entity-to-its-corresponding-dbset-wi which *might* be what I'm looking for. I'm testing it now. Edit: Your snippet seems to make the compiler happy. I'm going to test that too.

Comment: Mark, add your `db.set` code as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbContext` class has a non-generic method (and generic version, which may provide a better solution, depending on how you are calling this code) [`DbContext.Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) that takes the `Type` of the entity to query as a parameter.  Using this, your code would be:

```
'where obj is any EF model object in my context
Public Function GetSomeObject(obj as Object, id as long) as Object 
    Using db as ContextEntities = New ContextEntities
        Dim objType = obj.GetType()
        Dim someObject = db.Set(objType).Find(id)
        'do magic from here on
        ....
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great and is the approach I'm taking now. Thanks!